# Airpods disconnects when sound is played in ios app made on flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

Hi I created an application which uses the package audioplayers.dart it plays a small audio file periodically. But when I try to use my airpods pro to listen, they get disconnected as soon as the sound is played. I am not sue what is happening as it is playing perfectly fine in the android app using the same airpods pro.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.